# Better way to join null values than picking a magic value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, null

I need to join two tables that are more or less the same (one is a staging table data to go in the other).

Some of the columns are nullable, and when the values are null, the join in my merge statement does not match.  (This is normal behavior for nulls.)

The problem is that, when they don't match it causes the row to be deleted and recreated, Changing the value identity of the row in the actual table.

I know that I can do something like this to join nulls:

```
on coalesce(target.SomeId, -9999) = coalesce(source.SomeId, -9999)
```

But I don't like having to pick out a number that I hope will never be used.  (It feels dirty.)

Is there a better way to make a join on a nullable column than using a magic number like this?

Answer (score 5):

Let's go with this:

```
target.SomeId = source.SomeId
   or (target.SomeId is null and source.SomeId is null)
```

Conceptually, this should make sense.  That is, either both values are null or both values are equal to each other.  This should also perform better as the coalesce forces a table scan.  I've converted the coalesce style to that above and seen tremendous performance gains.

Answer (score 3):

I almost exclusively use the following pattern

```
ON EXISTS (SELECT target.SomeId INTERSECT source.SomeId)
```

after picking it up from [Paul White's blog post here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
ON ((target.SomeId IS NULL) AND (source.SomeId IS NULL)) 
OR ((target.SomeId IS NOT NULL) AND (source.SomeId IS NOT NULL) 
AND (target.SomeId = source.SomeId)))
```

Comment: The second condition (checking that both sides are not null) seems redundant; a null value won't compare as equal to one that isn't.

Comment: This is what Linq2Sql generates when you do `Object.Equals(target.SomeId, source.SomeId)`

Comment: Fair enough, but I'd bet that it gets optimized away.

Comment: @BenThul It does seem strange, but there must be a reason to why MS added it.

Comment: Good reason? Ha ha - MS does a lot of strange things for bad reason - Visual Source Safe, CodePlex, Nokia, all of which are now dead, [trying to take down Google](http://www.smh.com.au/news/technology/microsoft-ceo-im-going-to-fing-kill-google/2005/09/03/1125302772214.html), saying that [Linux is a malignant cancer](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2001/06/02/ballmer_linux_is_a_cancer/) - well they've sure come around, and too many other things to mention. Hopefull the universe will "optimise them away".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean columns that aren't part of the joining key, then

```
...and (isnull(source.ColX, target.ColX) = isnull(target.ColX, source.ColX)
        or (source.ColX is null and target.ColX is null))
```

should cover all possibilities: the first line catches if both values are not null or *only* one value is not null, and the second line catches if *both* are null. Pretty ugly, but then that's what happens when you get too many nulls in your system.

Answer (score 0):

The result is strange and contains rows resulted from `INNER JOIN` and rows resulted from a `CROSS JOIN` betwen `NULL` IDs from source and target table (ex. {S-C, T-C}, {S-C, T-D}, {S-C, T-E}, {S-D, T-C}, {S-D, T-D}, {S-D, T-E},).

Look at this example:

```
DECLARE @Source TABLE (SomeId INT NULL, Name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);
DECLARE @Target TABLE (SomeId INT NULL, Name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);

INSERT  @Source VALUES (1,'S-A'),(2,'S-B'),(NULL,'S-C'),(NULL,'S-D');
INSERT  @Target VALUES (1,'T-A'),(2,'T-B'),(NULL,'T-C'),(NULL,'T-D'),(NULL,'T-E'),(6,'T-F');

SELECT  s.*, t.*
FROM    @Source s
INNER JOIN @Target t ON s.SomeId = t.SomeId OR s.SomeId IS NULL AND t.SomeId IS NULL;

SELECT  s.*, t.*
FROM    @Source s
INNER JOIN @Target t ON ISNULL(s.SomeId,-9999) = ISNULL(t.SomeId,-9999);
```

Results:

```
SomeId      Name       SomeId      Name
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------
1           S-A        1           T-A <- INNER JOIN
2           S-B        2           T-B <- INNER JOIN
NULL        S-C        NULL        T-C <- "CROSS JOIN"
NULL        S-C        NULL        T-D <- "CROSS JOIN"
NULL        S-C        NULL        T-E <- "CROSS JOIN"
NULL        S-D        NULL        T-C <- "CROSS JOIN"
NULL        S-D        NULL        T-D <- "CROSS JOIN"
NULL        S-D        NULL        T-E <- "CROSS JOIN"
```

Answer (score -1):

Special characters?
Else you can try:

```
on (target.SomeId is null OR source.SomeId is null OR target.SomeId = source.SomeId)
```